# AsyncTask which allows to handle exceptions on UI

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, error-handling

The `AsyncTask` available in android, gives you the result from `doInBackground` on the UI thread so that you can update UI according to the result, but exceptions need to be handled inside `doInBackground` function.

So following is my generic solution to the problem, the main objective here is to allow user to handle exceptions exactly the same way he does when working with synchronous code.

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskWithThrowable<Params, Progress, Result>  {

    public class ResultHolder<Result> {

        private ResultHolder(Result result) {
            _result = result;
        }

        private ResultHolder(Throwable throwable) {
            _throwable = throwable;
        }

        private Throwable _throwable = null;

        private Result _result;

        public Result getResult() throws Throwable{
            if (_throwable != null) {
                throw _throwable;
            }

            return _result;
        }
    }

    private AsyncTask<Params, Progress, ResultHolder<Result>> _asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, ResultHolder<Result>>() {
        @Override
        protected ResultHolder<Result> doInBackground(Params... params)  {

            try {
                return new ResultHolder<Result>(AsyncTaskWithThrowable.this.doInBackground(params));
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                new ResultHolder<Result>(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            AsyncTaskWithThrowable.this.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResultHolder<Result> result) {
            AsyncTaskWithThrowable.this.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
            AsyncTaskWithThrowable.this.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    };

    public abstract Result doInBackground(Params ... params) throws Throwable;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    protected void onPostExecute(ResultHolder<Result> resultHolder) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
    }

    public final AsyncTaskWithThrowable<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
         _asyncTask.execute(params);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it.

```
new AsyncTaskWithThrowable<Boolean, Void, String>(){

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Boolean ...params) {
        if (!params[0]) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException();
        }
        return "result";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ResultHolder<String> resultHolder) {
        try{
            String result = resultHolder.getResult();
            // Change UI
        }
        catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
            // Change UI
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            // I don't like this catch block, but i couldn't find a way to avoid it.
        }
    }
}.execute(false);
```

The problem I see with it is user is forced to handle `Throwable` (also `doInBackground` can throw anything), but I cannot use typed parameter for exception here, as Java doesn't allow to catch it.

Comment: After having received answers, please do not add revised versions of your code to your question or modify your previous code in such a way that it invalidates answers. See our meta question [Can I edit my own question to include revised code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/can-i-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-code-also-how-to-handle-iterativ) for what you can do after having received answers to your question.

Comment: Consider Callable<T> and Future<T> with your own Executor

Answer (score 5):

First of all, a few notes:

- `ResultHolder<Result>` can be a `public static class`.
- This just feels wrong:

  ```
  catch (Throwable e) {
      new ResultHolder<Result>(e);
      return null;
  }
  ```

  You should probably return that `ResultHolder`, shouldn't you?
- Avoid `@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})`. If you have a warning there, then find out why it is there and solve it. Don't mark it as ignored. Sometimes, marking warnings ignored this way is fine, I would never do it with an `UnusedDeclaration` warning though.

As for your question about the `Throwable`, you are right that it is not a good idea to use that there. You can solve this by wrapping the exception in another.

```
public class AsyncException extends Exception {
    public AsyncException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public abstract Result doInBackground(Params ... params) throws AsyncException;

public Result getResult() throws AsyncException {

private ResultHolder(AsyncException throwable) {

@Override
protected ResultHolder<Result> doInBackground(Params... params)  {
    try {
        return new ResultHolder<Result>(AsyncTaskWithThrowable.this.doInBackground(params));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResultHolder<Result>(new AsyncException("Error while performing doInBackground", e));
    }
}
```

Problem solved! Note that I changed to catching `Exception` instead of `Throwable` as Errors (throwables that are not exceptions) shouldn't really be caught, they are much more serious so they are meant to crash everything.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i agree with most of the things you mentioned and have updated my code accordingly. But I have couple of things, first regarding suppressing `UnusedDeclaration`, i have to do this because i want those methods to have empty body (so the extending class can optionally implement them), and this causes the parameter to be unused.

Comment: @Ammar OK, then I understand what you're suppressing, I thought the warning was for something else.